# Cannot get my HTML to pass the W3 Validator. What is wrong?

Tags: html, w3c-validation

I am trying to validate one page, but the validator gives me ridiculous errors.

For example, Attribute **name** not allowed on element **meta** at this point.

I am using `<meta name="description"`

https://validator.w3.org/nu/?showsource=yes&doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ayurvedabansko.bg%2F

The client wants his code validated, but this is crazy...

How can I fix this?

Comment: The validator is clearly showing a non-closed link tag. Why not fix the errors shown and not get stuck on a single one, which is actually caused by other errors? A good editor would show this problem immediately.

Comment: I've tried everything. It even showed me that the title tag is missing, when it was fist after the <head>

Comment: The validator for some reason thinks that all this is in the body, not in the head. Which is crazy...

Comment: The validator is also showing that on line 17 you have some invalid character as the first character that is causing it to assume body has already started. Remove that.

Comment: In the white space in line 17 before the tag is some invalid character. remove it and the validator doesn't complain no more. The validator works fine, your file is messed.

Comment: Yes, I have <?php which contains important php functions that auto get the dynamic title and description.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed some issues, and validating your HTML source now returns two INFO messages only.

You main problem seems to be a closing div tag without its opening match.

Search for `<a href="#" class="scrollToTop"></a>`
and remove the closing div tag right afterwards.

Here's the list of fixes I applied:

- Closing div tag without opening match (as mentioned)
- `<hgroup>` being outdated/deprecated (try replacing it with a div or a p (besides a div does not support nesting `hgroup` tags (among others) inside it)
- Make your `<title>` tag the first child in your head element

---

**Update**: It seems you need to define the charset as the first thing before proceeding inside the head tag.

Also, I got rid of http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html". Is this really needed?

Making your `<head>` look like

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Аюрведа клиник - лечение, пречистване, подмладяване.</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Аюрведа клиник Лъки Банско е първият в България индийски център, съчетаващ лечение по системата Аюрведа с пълно пречистване на организма, разкрасяване и подмладяване по методите Пурвакарма и Панчакарма."/>
    <meta name="keywords" content="Аюрведа клиник Лъки Банско е първият в България индийски център, съчетаващ лечение по системата Аюрведа с пълно пречистване на организма, разкрасяване и подмладяване по методите Пурвакарма и Панчакарма." />
    <meta name="robots" content="INDEX, follow" />
    <meta name="revisit-after" content="3 days" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <base href="http://www.ayurvedabansko.bg/" />
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.ayurvedabansko.bg/" />
    <link rel="alternate" href="http://www.ayurvedabansko.bg/" hreflang="bg" />
    <link rel="alternate" href="http://www.ayurvedabansko.bg/en/" hreflang="en" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/default.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/jquery.fancybox.css" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/jquery.datepick.css" />
     <link rel="icon" href="/images/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>
```

will make it **pass validation.**

---

**Update 2**: [credits to Reeno](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32035892/cannot-get-my-html-pass-w3-validator-what-is-wrong#comment51974042_32036131). This is the answer.

[image]

Comment: I cannot put the title to be right after the head, because it shows even more errors. I am getting the title with include functions.php and that causes all the problems. For some reason the validator doesn't like starting the <?php code

Comment: I don't know what you need to do - all I know is that I entered http://www.ayurvedabansko.bg/, saved it into a local file, played with it till I got no errors anymore. In my answer I list what were the fixes I applied. I did it in a different order, though, I started with the title thing, afterwards hgroup and only then I got to the </div> issue. I listed it in a different order assuming that this non-matched closing div may be causing other problems.

Comment: Let's try to isolate the errors... striping your html source of all your meta tags, leaving only a single one like <meta charset="UTF-8" /> leaves you with no errors. Now we need to try to locate in which meta tag the problem lies.

Comment: The error on the current live site is still the same as written above in the comments: There's an invalid character at line 17. When this is fixed, all other errors are gone, too

Comment: ninjaprog, Reeno is absolutely right. I must have done this in my "fixing scenarios" and did not give it attention, but this must have been the reason for why my fixes passed. If you do strictly what Reeno is saying - just remove whatever character(s) there are at line 17, before <meta>, you will get no errors whatsoever.

Comment: Unfortunately still not helping. As I said, in line 17 I have some <?php including functions.php. But I need this, cannot remove it. Thanks for the efford gyus. Maybe it's just some bug in the validator.

Comment: Please add to your question body the exact php statement you have there.

Comment: @ninjaprog: There's definitely no bug in the validator. Somewhere in your PHP function you're echo'ing this invisible character. Examine your PHP and strip it down to the bare minimum to find the error.